# Lock show action for only one user at the same time

Tags: jquery, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm looking for the best solution to the following problem.

Employees of online store will use this application.
 Employees need work with orders but application must lock order for another employee when one of them looking in order (other employee can not open order).

So, I'm looking the way to make this lock.

I have only one idea. In show view I can put jquery script with loop that will be send async request with increase the lockout time. When employee leave order, then lock expire after a few seconds.

Do you have any better ideas?

Comment: You can have `checkedOutBy` field in your database, and if it is opened by an employee, you would disable click event on that order. And as soon as employee closes the order page, you send another request to the database to unlock it by updating the `checkOutBy` field to `null`.

Comment: How can I send request when user close order (ex. close browser tab, click back page,  hard reset computer), via Jquery?

Comment: there is `.onbeforeunload()` event handler that would handle browser closing or navigating away events. Your only problem would be when user hard resets the computer.